# Xamarin Forms : Data Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have set the binding source of "IsVisible" property to a public variable in the code behind without following MVVM. In this case, even though the state of the variable is changed, the view (in this case ListView) is still visible.

```
private void btnNotifications_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ActivateControlButton(sender as Button))
    {
        Remove_ChildElements_InUserCOntrol();
        return;
    }

    Is_MainTaskList_Visible = false;
}
```

My xml code is:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="lstUserTasks"
          Grid.Row="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding User_Task_Groups}"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
          FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemSelected="lstUserTasks_ItemSelected"
          ItemTapped="lstUserTasks_ItemTapped"
          IsVisible="{Binding Is_MainTaskList_Visible}">
```

Can someone help?

How to notify the UI thread that this propery is changed?

Comment: is `Is_MainTaskList_Visible` a **public property**?  Does the class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below:

```
 public class UserViewModel
{

    public UserViewModel()
    {
        CreateCollection();
        Is_MainTaskList_Visible = true;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<User> User_Task_Groups { get; set; }
    public bool Is_MainTaskList_Visible { get; set; }
    public void CreateCollection()
    {
        User_Task_Groups = new ObservableCollection<User>()
        {
            new User(){ Name="A"},
            new User(){ Name="B"},
            new User(){ Name="C"},
        };

    }
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:UserViewModel></local:UserViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
        <ListView x:Name="lstUserTasks" Grid.Row="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding User_Task_Groups}"   FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemSelected="lstUserTasks_ItemSelected"
          ItemTapped="lstUserTasks_ItemTapped" IsVisible="{Binding Is_MainTaskList_Visible}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```